# Trying to change the x-position-variable, but only the value changes, not the position of the ctx

Tags: javascript, canvas, position, var, mousemove

I'm trying to make a click and drag functionality, so that when I click and hold, I will be able to move a "brick". But when I try to change the x-position to `e.clientX` inside my `mousemove` eventListener, only the value of the variable changes, and the brick doesn't change position. Even if i simply change the x-position to a number, nothing but the value changes. I tried console.log the `var`, and as I said, the value changes.

```js
var brick1 = { //my brick variables
 x: 0, 
 y: 0, 
 width: brickWidth, 
 height: brickHeight,
 img: "media/brick.png",
 clicked: false
 };
  
var myBrick1 = new object(brick1.img, brick1.x, brick1.y, brick1.width, brick1.height); //my actual brick object

document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);
function mouseMoveHandler(e){
  var mouseX = e.clientX - (canvas.offsetLeft+10);
  var mouseY = e.clientY - (canvas.offsetTop+10);

  if(brick1.clicked){
    brick1.x = 120; //The value changes, but not the position
    brick1.x = mouseX - (brick1.width/2);
    console.log(brick1.clicked);
    console.log(brick1.x);
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening? And hopefully how to fix it?
Let me know if you need more samples from my code to see the issue.

Comment: can you show us your render / draw function please?

Comment: How do i post a comment that includes JS?

Comment: You change the value of `brick1` and `console.log(brick1)` but all your draw functions render is `myBrick1` and `myBrick2`.  It appears you are expecting to see a visual change on an object you are not rendering?

Comment: You can edit your post or put it back in that comment, I was able to read it before you removed it though.

Comment: I see it now so you create a `new object` and pass in brick1 but then your constructor (thought I can't see it) copies by `value` and not `reference` so the changes to brick1 don't affect `myBrick1` and `myBrick2`

Comment: If you look at the 'var' 'myBrick1' you can see that I use the brick1.x position. You should also know that when I change the value of the same 'var' ('brick1.x') **outside** the function, the position changes.

Comment: Well how would you suggest I fix it? Im not familiar with the 'reference' you mentioned.

Comment: I added an answer.  Yes outside the function if it is before you construct the object you would see the position change when the draw executed later.  I put a longer explanation below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expecting a pass by value to work as a pass by reference in your constructor.

```
var myBrick1 = new object(brick1.img, brick1.x, brick1.y, brick1.width, brick1.height); //my actual brick object
```

Here you use a `new object` to construct from the values of `brick1` and assign to the new object. I assumed your constructor looks something like

```
function object(img, x, y, w, h) {
  this.img = img;  /* object so reference assignment */
  this.x = x;      /* number so value assignment */
  this.y = y;      /* number so value assignment */
  this.w = w;      /* number so value assignment */
  this.h = h;      /* number so value assignment */
  /* some methods ect... */
}
```

when you then change the value of brick1

```
if(brick1.clicked){
  brick1.x = 120; //The value changes, but not the position
  brick1.x = mouseX - (brick1.width/2);
  console.log(brick1.clicked);
  console.log(brick1.x);
}
```

This only changes the brick1 values of properties `x` and `y`. Since they were passed to the objects as values not references.

You can change your code to

```
myBrick1.x = 120;
```

It is a good thing this doesn't assign by reference or all your bricks would have the same x, y coordinates.  Full altered statement:

```
if(brick1.clicked) {
  myBrick1.x = 120; //The value changes, but not the position
  myBrick1.x = mouseX - (myBrick1.width/2);
  console.log(brick1.clicked);
  console.log(brick1.x);
}
```

Comment: No problem your whole brick.clicked part looks really fishy too.  You should be doing a `point(mouseX, mouseY)` to bounding `box(brick.x, brick.y, brick.w, brick.h)` collision check for every brick and only change the `instance` of the brick to clicked.

Comment: I tried changing to myBrick1.x = 120; but still the same thing happened. The value changes but not the position.

Comment: Newer mind, I changed it to myBrick1.X instead of lower-case x. Now its working! Thanks!